# Monitor process start time, end time using shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, node.js

I am working on project in which we execute shell script which invokes the Node process and further processing happens. I want to design a script which should log the start time, termination time of the process created by the shell script which invoke Node.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If your using Bash, there is the command called `date`.

```
#!/bin/bash
date > /path/to/your/logfile;
node your_program && date >> /path/to/your/logfile
```

naturally you will have to add your node program and whatever arguments after `node` in the script, and you will have to designate the your logfile, but that should output the time (granted milliseconds before) your program starts, and the time your program ends. You can even format the `date` command to output the time in a way that's the most meaningful to you. Have fun benchmarking!

Comment: Hey @knotech, thanks for posting comment. I am thinking that when my shell file (script_import.sh) is been called. Can i get the time of node process creation and when it completes its execution, then time of termination ? is it possible in any case.

Comment: Have updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: How about using cron tab to call one shell script file which in turn checks for the node process and as soon as it didnt found it, it logs the current time ?

Comment: Cron runs at regular intervals so, you would only get precision within the interval designated by cron to run the check script, to check. The method above while not perfectly precise, (especially if you are really trying time a child process spawned by the script) will give you better precision.

Comment: How about running a cron job at 2 ms interval and calling shell file to check for process exist state.? We dont need exact time, interval of some milliseconds will be tolerable. can i use ps with grep to find node process ID and time accordingly.